# What is PostgreSQL equivalent for MSSQL msdb.dbo.sp_start_job?

Tags: postgresql

What is PostgreSQL equivalent for MSSQL EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'jobName'? Does anyone know is there such a procedure in Postgres?

Comment: Postgres does not have a built-in scheduler. Use the operating system's ability (e.g. `cron`) or tools like `pg_cron` or `pg_timetable`